# Does EF Core have a connection pool?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The `DbContext` of EF Core is scoped in the ASP.NET Core services. So a new `DbContext` is created on each request. Does this mean that a new connection is opened on each request, including all the overhead like logging in to the database? Or is there a connection pool that is independent of the `DbContext`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying ADO.NET provider like System.Data.SqlClient usually implements a connection pool