# Entity Framework Core: different threads using the same instance of DbContext

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The application was developed on ASP NET Core 3. To log user actions, I decided to use a single method in the Project class. Faced the problem of using one singleton dbContext from different threads.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionDB");
    services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection), ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

    services.AddSingleton<Project>();
}
```

**Project.cs**

```
public async Task AddUserLog(string action, string message, int userId)
{
    try
    {
        UserLog userLog = new UserLog()
        {
            Action = action,
            Message = message,
            UserId = userId
            Datepoint = DateTime.Now
        };

        _dbContext.UserLog.Add(userLog);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await AddSystemLog("Project", "AddUserLog", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**SchemeController.cs**

```
public class SchemeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Project _project;

    public SchemeController(Project project)
    {
        _project = project;
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "AdvancedControl")]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task SomeMethode()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await _project.AddUserLog("Text", "Message", 42);
        }       
    }
}
```

Already at the second iteration of the loop, I catch an exception in the AddUserLog method:
"*A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext*."

I suggest several solutions:

1. Add the log to the buffer table and then save it to the database by timer. But this is not the best way out;
2. Block the method while it is being saved to the database.

But I don’t like any of the options.

Please tell me the correct approach in solving this issue.

Comment: Never use DbContext like this. Do you really need `Project` to be a singleton?

Comment: @DavidG The 'project' also performs other tasks. Logging is one of the tasks that I wanted to implement in it. Why do not recommend?

Comment: Because if you make it a singleton, you capture the DbContext permanently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you trying to use shared resource (singleton `Project` class) to perform parallel operations (save `UserLog`s) while your shared resource implementation is not thread-safe (exceptions raised).

You have at lease three ways to solve this:

1. Do not use shared resource: register `Project` per scope instead of singletone;
2. Do not perform operations in parallel: seems hard to achieve because you making webapp and you can't force user(s) to wait
3. Refactor your resource to be thread-safe: add locks/mutexes/buffering... inside `Project`

There is no one "correct" way - all 3 are correct. Choose one you like (or combine several).

*Usually* using scoped dbcontext is recommended ([because connections are pooled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635538/does-ef-core-have-a-connection-pool)), but it's the creator of app who should decide.

Comment: The Project class is singleton. And if I'm not mistaken, then it is possible to use dbcontext for it too, only singleton. I will create a preliminary buffer table and block it while archiving to the database.

Comment: Making DbContext singletone will make it singletone for all other usages (other controllers). You will receive same errors (second operations started...) in your "regular" controllers.

Comment: Tell me please how to get dbContext for Project class correctly?

Comment: (1) use scoped; (2) make 2 dbcontext - one singleton for UserLog table, second scoped for other tables; (3) obtain IScopeServiceFactory and create your own scope inside Project. And you still need invent your own thread-safety for 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I put common buffer tables into a singleton class. I rewrote the Project class so that now it is scoped and is called once at the start of the project.